# ArcMap Crashes in Remote Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation, arcgis-10.4, windows-server-2016, remote-desktop

Windows Server 2016

ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.1

I've installed ArcGIS 10.4.1 on Windows Server 2016. When I connect to the server through Remote Desktop, ArcMap crashes on launch. ArcCatalog will launch while connected in RDP. However, I can launch ArcMap without any issues when physically on the server. I can open ArcMap on the server and then remotely connect and it will continue to function, but it will not launch a new instance.

I've tried deleting the normal template, updating the registry for the Python 2.7 installation, uninstalling Python, etc. None of those should be the problem since it works fine outside of RDP.

I don't know much about dump files, but the Exception Information is "The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access." So, assuming it's trying to access something on the client machine? I've tried checking and unchecking all of the local resources.

I'm pretty sure I initially installed it while connected through RDP, but I uninstalled and reinstalled while not in RDP and that didn't change anything either. Not sure if I've missed something with Remote Desktop on the server.

Any ideas?

I've hit a dead end and didn't get an answer on the Esri forums.

Comment: Server 2016 isn't in the supported platform list for ArcGIS 10.4.1, having only been added at 10.5 (and only with VDI/Citrix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @Vince:

> [Windows] Server 2016 isn't in the supported platform list for ArcGIS [Desktop] 10.4.1,
>   having only been added at 10.5 (and only with VDI/Citrix)